# How to center "Avatar" material UI component inside div? Ussing ReactJS and material UI

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

im trying to center an avatar material ui component inside my project, i tried many things including  text align, justify content, margin auto but nothing seems to work. Any help would be appreciated

/////profile.js///////

```
 <div className="myProfile__outterContainer">
      <div className="myProfile__innerContainer">
        <div className="myProfile__header">
          <h2>My Profile</h2>
          <Avatar
            alt={user.displayName}
            src={user.photoURL}
            className={classes.large}
          />
          <h2>Welcome, {user.displayName}</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

 
////// profile .css below
profile.css

    .myProfile__outterContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 5vh;
}

.myProfile__innerContainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 85vw;
  height: 75vh;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  box-shadow: 0px 18px 53px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.myProfile__header {
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to center the both `<h2>` tags and the Avatar vertically :

```
.myProfile__header {
  display : flex;
  flex-direction : column;
  align-items : center;
  justify-content : center;
}
```